# Error on executing sample code in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver; //"org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver" cannot be resolved
public class brff {public static void main(String[] args) {       
FirefoxDriver f= new FirefoxDriver();}}
```

Have included all jars for the project:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont see selenium jar in the visible part of the pic given in the question. Try adding selenium-standalone-server jar from this link:

http://goo.gl/PJUZfa

or

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ (Download and add Selenium standalone jar)

Comment: Hi prishodak.. have added java selenium client version 2.48.2.Is that not sufficient..?

Comment: WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();  Also you should be using Webdriver interface instead of FirefoxDriver for creating the instance.

Comment: driver instance would let me access only functions present in WebDriver interface[defined in FirefoxDriver]...Will try your suggestion.As am a novice for selenium & am not sure on the importance of "WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); " code yet..Will try this for sure.

Comment: webdriver is interface. you can initialize the driver object with firefox/chrome/android etc without changing our code.  Also if your problem is solved, pls accept the reply as answer.